# Writing my own version of 'fgets()' in C

Tags: c, file, fgets

I want to create my own version of the function `fgets()`.
I tried to do this but has run into some problems.
Please let me know where am I going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *my_fgets(char my_string[], int bytes, const char *filename) {
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't open the file");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (sizeof(my_string) < bytes || my_string[i] != '\n')
        my_string[i++] = getc(fp);

    my_string[i] = '\0';        //adding NULL character at the end

    /*   using pointers
    char *p;
    for (p = array; p < array + bytes; p++)
        *p = getc(fp);    
    *p = '\0';  */    

    fclose(fp);
    return my_string;    
}

int main() {
    char my_string[15];
    int n;
    char *p;

    p = my_fgets(my_string, sizeof(my_string), stdin);    

    printf("\n%s", my_string);
    printf("\n%s", p);

    return 0;
}
```

My output is not running, it immediately crashes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Standard `fgets()` does not open a file; unless you've been given strictures from a tutor, neither should yours.

Comment: Note that the loop with `while (sizeof(my_string) < bytes …)`, is misguided. The size is the number of bytes in a pointer (4 or 8, probably) and won't change.

Comment: I'll edit that part and put 'strlen' instead. thanks

Comment: `my_string[i] != '\n'` : Value(`my_string[i]`) has not been determined.

Comment: `< bytes` should be `< bytes - 1`

Comment: I'm also getting:    Warning: passing argument 3 of 'my_fgets' from incompatible pointer type.    Why is this? I thought I was passing a character pointer. Not sure why is it incompatible.

Comment: 3rd argument type is `const char *filename` but `stdin` is `FILE*`.

Comment: When no characters are read, `my_fgets()` should return `NULL`.  When an input error (see `ferror()`) occurs, `my_gets()` should also return `NULL`.    `fgets()`  includes `\n` in the buffer, this code does not.

Comment: *I'll edit that part and put 'strlen' instead* Don't. `strlen` requires a null-terminated string. Why not just use `i`? That's the number of characters you've read so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your *implementation* of `fgets()` has many major problems:

- The prototype is incorrect: the last argument should be a stream pointer (`FILE *`), not a filename (`const char *`). You invoke your function with `stdin`, which is indeed a stream not a filename. The compiler should produce a warning for this mistake. IMHO this warning should be an error. Enable all compiler warnings and do not ignore them: `gcc -Wall -W -Werror`.
- To open a file for reading as text, you should use a mode string of `"r"`, not `"wb"` which will truncate the file, but since the function should receive a `FILE *`, this is a moot point.
- The test in `while (sizeof(my_string) < bytes || my_string[i] != '\n')` is incorrect for many reasons: you should compare `i` with the array size, not `sizeof(my_string)` which a constant, the size of a pointer, and you should compare the byte read from the file, not `my_string[i]` to which you have not stored anything yet. Furthermore, you should use the logical and operator (`&&`) to combine these tests, not logical or (`||`).
- The final `'\n'` should be stored into the destination array.
- You do not return `NULL` at end of file.
- You do not handle the special case of a zero buffer size.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *my_fgets(char my_string[], int bytes, FILE *fp) {
    int c, i = 0;

    if (bytes <= 0)
        return my_string;

    while (i < bytes - 1 && ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        my_string[i++] = c;
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
    }
    my_string[i] = '\0'; //adding NUL character at the end

    if (i > 0) {
        return my_string;
    } else {
        return NULL;  // no character read at end of file
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char my_string[15];
    int n;
    char *p;

    p = my_fgets(my_string, sizeof(my_string), stdin);

    printf("%s\n", my_string);
    printf("%s\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, I'll go over it carefully.